# What to do when boot-repair warns to change pc from legacy to efi mode?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, boot-repair

On my dual boot machine with preinstalled Windows 8, while trying to setup boot with boot repair it returns info that EFI is detected and warns me to change my pc from legacy to efi mode.

"Boot-Repair extra info" is at http://paste.ubuntu.com/6558138/.

What to do to create a dual Windows 8/Ubuntu boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow the Boot-Repair instructions. When asked if you want to enable WindowsEFI renaming, answer `Yes`. If any issue, indicate the URL that will appear.